# How to pass system properties to Grails 3 database migration commands

Tags: grails, gradle, database-migration, system-properties

I am trying to pass system property to dbm commands - e.g.:

`grails -Ddb.host=localhost dbm-gorm-diff`

But system properties are ignored.

I have tried to add the following to `build.gradle`:

```
[bootRun, test, dbmUpdate, dbmGormDiff, runCommand].each { task ->
    configure(task) {
        systemProperties = System.properties
    }
}
```

It works for `run-app` but not for dbm commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `run-command` seems to work:

`grails -Ddb.host=localhost run-command dbm-gorm-diff`

Answer (score 1):

You can define this more generally for all commands, regardless of how you execute them.

```
project.tasks.withType(ApplicationContextCommandTask) {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Comment: With this I get `Error initializing classpath: Could not get unknown property 'ApplicationContextCommandTask' for root project` - Anyhow the problem is that regardless of configuration used (explicit or general) system properties are not working for dbm commands. Only workaround I have found so far is to use `run-command`.